Problems loading the “caret” library with R Language for IntelliJ plugin
When I try to load "caret" package in Pycharm with R Language for IntelliJ I have the following error:
Pycharm:
> library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() to 'lubridate', details:
call: system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
error: 4 arguments passed to .Internal(system) which requires 2 or 3

I have installed both the “caret” package and the “lubridate” package and configured the .libPaths() with the same directories as in Rstudio (where both packages work perfectly).
> packageVersion("caret")
[1] ‘6.0.94’
> packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.9.3’

> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4"
[2] "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/R/library"          
[3] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                        
[4] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                              
[5] "/usr/lib/R/library" 

RStudio:
> library(caret)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: lattice

> packageVersion("caret")
[1] ‘6.0.94’
> packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.9.3’

> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4"
[2] "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/R/library"          
[3] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                        
[4] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                              
[5] "/usr/lib/R/library"   

Load "caret" package in Pycharm with R language for IntelliJ.

It may be a dumb question... you've installed the IntelliJ plugin and enabled it?
